# Request does not match any route issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I have creating a extension for get cms static block content using rest api.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\PageManagerInterface"
                type="Snowdog\CmsApi\Model\PageManager" />
    <preference for="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface"
                type="Snowdog\CmsApi\Model\BlockManager" />
    <preference for="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\BlockInterface"
                type="Snowdog\CmsApi\Model\Block" />
    <preference for="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\PageInterface"
                type="Snowdog\CmsApi\Model\Page" />
    <preference for="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\PageSearchResultsInterface"
                type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />
    <preference for="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\BlockSearchResultsInterface"
                type="Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults" />
    <type name="Snowdog\CmsApi\Model\BlockManager">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collectionProcessor" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\BlockCollectionProcessor</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Snowdog\CmsApi\Model\PageManager">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collectionProcessor" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\PageCollectionProcessor</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**webapi.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <!-- Cms Page -->
    <route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsPage/:pageId" method="GET">
        <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\PageManagerInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Cms::page"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsPageIdentifier/:identifier/storeId/:storeId" method="GET">
        <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\PageManagerInterface" method="getByIdentifier"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Cms::page"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsPage/search" method="GET">
        <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\PageManagerInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Cms::page"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <!-- Cms Block -->
    <route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock/:blockId" method="GET">
        <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Cms::block"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsBlockIdentifier/:identifier/storeId/:storeId" method="GET">
        <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface" method="getByIdentifier"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
    <route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock/search" method="GET">
        <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Cms::block"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

2. **passing url**

http://vaibhav.local/rest/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock?29

3. **getting error**

When I am hit URL I got **Request does not match any route.** issue.

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks In advance..!

Comment: You should try with this `rest/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock/:29`

Comment: its not working bro

Comment: can you share your `di.xml` code and `BlockManagerInterface` code?

Comment: please check my updated question

Answer (score 3):

Your endpoint should be:

> rest/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock/29

instead of

> rest/V1/snowdog/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock?29

UPDATE: it should be routes not route.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock/:blockId" method="GET">
        <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Cms::block"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Comment: i am passing this ...http://vaibhav.local/rest/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock?29

Comment: test my answer, and make sure your method is set to GET

Comment: are you using postman?

Comment: yes using postman and also method Get

Comment: did you run upgrade?

Comment: yes i have done upgrade

Comment: found the error it should be routes not route

Comment: the closing tag

Comment: let me check once

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: how about the other endpoint, are they working? or the same not working?

Comment: others are working ..products categories,

Comment: how about this one `http://vaibhav.local/index.php/rest/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock?29` ?

Comment: did you check it?

Comment: Yes its not working

Comment: can  you try `/V1/cmsBlock/snowdog/:blockId` and check

Comment: getting error       "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Cms::block"
    },

Comment: which token auth you are using , customer or admin?

Comment: or try to change resource ref to `anonymous` then check if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91812/discussion-between-sarvesh-tiwari-and-magefms).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your web service as

> rest/V1/snowdog/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock?29

You need to call it like

> rest/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock?29

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step and verify your code.

**Step 1 :** Make sure you have enabled `**Snowdog_CmsApi** module.

**Step 2 :**

> etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface"
            type="Snowdog\CmsApi\Model\BlockManager" />
```

**Step 3 :**

> etc/webapi.xml

```
<!-- Cms Block -->
<route url="/V1/snowdog/cmsBlock/:blockId" method="GET">
    <service class="Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface" method="getById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Cms::block"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

**Step 4 :**

> Api/BlockManagerInterface.php

```
<?php
 namespace Snowdog\CmsApi\Api;
 interface BlockManagerInterface
 {
/**
 * @param int $blockId
 * @return \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface
 */
public function getById($blockId);
/**
 * @param string $identifier
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return \Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getByIdentifier($identifier, $storeId = null);
/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
 * @return \Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\BlockSearchResultsInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface 
$searchCriteria);
}
```

**Step 5**

> Model/BlockManager.php

```
<?php
 namespace Snowdog\CmsApi\Model;
 use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
 use Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface;
 use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory;
 use Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block;
 use Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider;
 use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
 use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
 use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation;
 use Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\BlockManagerInterface;
 use Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\BlockInterfaceFactory;
 use Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\BlockSearchResultsInterfaceFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\App\State;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
 /**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
 class BlockManager extends ManagerBase implements BlockManagerInterface
 {
/**
 * @var BlockRepositoryInterface
 */
private $blockRepository;
/**
 * @var FilterProvider
 */
private $filterProvider;
/**
 * @var BlockFactory
 */
private $blockFactory;
/**
 * @var Block
 */
private $blockResource;
/**
 * @var BlockSearchResultsInterfaceFactory
 */
private $searchResultsFactory;
/**
 * @var Block\CollectionFactory
 */
private $blockCollectionFactory;
/**
 * @var CollectionProcessorInterface
 */
private $collectionProcessor;
/**
 * @var BlockInterfaceFactory
 */
private $blockDtoFactory;
/**
 * @var DataObjectHelper
 */
private $dataObjectHelper;
/**
 * @var State
 */
private $appState;
/**
 * @var Emulation
 */
private $emulation;
/**
 * @param BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
 * @param FilterProvider $filterProvider
 * @param BlockFactory $blockFactory
 * @param Block $blockResource
 * @param Block\CollectionFactory $blockCollectionFactory
 * @param BlockSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory
 * @param CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor
 * @param BlockInterfaceFactory $blockDtoFactory
 * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
 * @param State $appState
 * @param Emulation $emulation
 */
public function __construct(
    BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
    FilterProvider $filterProvider,
    BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    Block $blockResource,
    Block\CollectionFactory $blockCollectionFactory,
    BlockSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory,
    CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor,
    BlockInterfaceFactory $blockDtoFactory,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    State $appState,
    Emulation $emulation
) {
    $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
    $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
    $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->blockResource = $blockResource;
    $this->searchResultsFactory = $searchResultsFactory;
    $this->blockCollectionFactory = $blockCollectionFactory;
    $this->collectionProcessor = $collectionProcessor;
    $this->blockDtoFactory = $blockDtoFactory;
    $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
    $this->appState = $appState;
    $this->emulation = $emulation;
}
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getById($blockId)
{
    $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($blockId);
    $content = $this->getBlockContentFiltered($block->getContent());
    $block->setContent($content);
    return $block;
}
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getByIdentifier($identifier, $storeId = null)
{
    $block = $this->blockFactory->create();
    $block->setStoreId($storeId);
    $this->blockResource->load($block, $identifier, BlockInterface::IDENTIFIER);
    if (!$block->getId()) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            __('CMS Block with identifier "%1" does not exist.', $identifier)
        );
    }
    $content = $this->getBlockContentFiltered($block->getContent());
    $block->setContent($content);
    return $block;
}
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    $storeId = $this->getStoreIdBySearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    $this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
    /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->blockCollectionFactory->create();
    $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);
    $items = [];
    /** @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Block $block */
    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $block) {
        $content = $this->getBlockContentFiltered($block->getContent());
        $block->setContent($content);
        $blockDto = $this->blockDtoFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $blockDto,
            $block->getData(),
            \Snowdog\CmsApi\Api\Data\BlockInterface::class
        );
        $blockDto->setId($block->getId());
        $items[] = $blockDto;
    }
    $searchResults = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
    $searchResults->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    $searchResults->setItems($items);
    $searchResults->setTotalCount(count($items));
    $this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
    return $searchResults;
}
/**
 * @param string $content
 * @return string
 */
private function getBlockContentFiltered($content)
{
    $emulatedResult = $this->appState->emulateAreaCode(
        Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
        [$this->filterProvider->getBlockFilter(), 'filter'],
        [$content]
    );
    return $emulatedResult;
}
}
```

> /rest/V1/snowdog/cmsPage/:pageId: retrieves page info by its id (integer value)

Take refrance from [Magento 2 CMS Api](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-cms-api/blob/master/Model/BlockManager.php)

I hope it helps!

Comment: its same code i have used same code